# Windows form in the assembly or environment outside the console environment

Tags: assembly

is it possible to make a Windows form in assembly language using code like C# and other languages, or for example, make something outside the console environment?

Comment: Sure. You can call API functions all the same, so you can use the Windows API too. Example 1: https://identity.pub/2018/11/01/asm-blank-window.html - Example 2: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1035362/Simple-Window-With-Assembly

Comment: For inspiration, here is a full application (an IDE for assembly projects, incidentally) written in assembly: https://github.com/mrfearless/RadASM2